# Wordpress footer location issue

Tags: wordpress-theming

I added additional menu to function "footer-menu":

```
  function register_theme_menus(){
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
        "header-menu" => __("Header Menu"),
        "footer-menu" => __("Footer Menu")
    )
  );
}
```

Here is code from footer.php :

```
<?php
        $args1 = array(
         "menu"        => "footer-menu",
         "menu_class"  => "nav navbar-nav",
         "container"   => "false",
         "fallback_cb" => "wp_page_menu",
         //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
         "walker" => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
        );
        wp_nav_menu($args1);
    ?>
```

But when I customizing in dashboard, it still assigned to header menu. Probably it is code issue but I can't find any solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tso0d.png)

Maybe someone had similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please can you change "menu" element inside the array to a theme_location.

```
<?php

    $args1 = array(
     "theme_location"        => "footer-menu",
     "menu_class"  => "nav navbar-nav",
     "container"   => "false",
     "fallback_cb" => "wp_page_menu",
     //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
     "walker" => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
    );
    wp_nav_menu($args1);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, you life saver. Here is post from Wordpress CODEX [link]https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/[link]. Probably it is out of date.